# What of few/a few/little/a little can be a noun?

Tags: nouns

I try to get known what of few/a few/little/a little we can use as noun. I would be grateful if you leave examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can all be used as nouns. Consider the following examples:

> Most people left before the storm hit. The *few* who remained did so because they had no means of transportation.
>
> Most people left before the storm hit but there were *a few* who stayed behind because they had no means of transportation
>
> There is lots of work get done but *little* time in which to do it.
>
> There is lots of work to be done but only *a little* time in which to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Both your examples of "few" are determiners modifying the pronoun "who". Both your examples of "little" are adjectives modifying the noun "time".

Comment: They are not nouns, and nor are they modifiers. "Few", "a few", "little" and "a little" are all determinatives. In your examples "the/a few" is a fused determiner-head NP, but "a few" is still a determinative, not a noun. In "(a) little", again this is a fused determiner-head NP, where "(a) little" is a determinative, not a noun

Answer (score 0):

"Few" is never a noun. It can be a pronoun (something that replaces a noun), or a determiner. From Wiktionary:

> ### few
>
> #### Determiner
>
> **few** (*comparative* **fewer** *or* **less**, *superlative* **fewest** *or* **least**)
>
> 1. (*preceded by another determiner*) An indefinite, but usually small, number of.
>
>    *I was expecting lots of people at the party, but very **few** (=almost none) turned up.   Quite a **few** of them (=many of them) were pleasantly surprised.   I don't know how many drinks I've had, but I've had a **few**.* [This usage is likely ironic.]
> 2. (*used alone*) Not many; a small (in comparison with another number stated or implied) but somewhat indefinite number of.
>
>    *There are **few** people who understand quantum theory.*
>
> #### Pronoun
>
> **few**
>
> 1. Few people, few things.
>      Many are called, but **few** are chosen.

"Little" is similar. See [little](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/little) at Wikipedia. They do have a definition of "little" as a noun, but it makes no sense to me and I believe it is a mistake:

> *Can I try a **little** of that sauce?* (makes sense)
>
> * *Can I try two **littles** of that sauce?* (makes no sense)

As well as being a pronoun and a determiner, "little" can be an adjective and an adverb. Wiktionary and most other dictionaries have examples for most of their entries.

See also Oxford Learner's Dictionaries:

- [little (determiner, pronoun)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/little_2)
- [little (adjective)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/little_1)
- [little (adverb)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/little_3)